# Creating a navigation menu of all posts of a custom post type and their children posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, navigation

I have a drop down menu that displays a link (the permalink) to all of the posts of a custom post type (county) and would simply like to display their children too this is the code I have so far but get_children is not working...

```
<ul>
    <?php $menu = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'county',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'desc'
    ) );
    while ( $menu->have_posts() ) : $menu->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <ul>
            <?php get_children(); ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

this is the code that allows me to assign on custom post type as the parent of another

```
function show_parent_metabox() {
    parent_select('county');
}

function parent_select ($parent_type) {
    global $post;
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = '{$parent_type}'         AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_title";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
    echo '<select name="parent_id" id="parent_id">';
    echo '<option value = "">None</option>';
    foreach ($results as $r) {
        echo '<option value="', $r->ID, '"', $r->ID == $post->post_parent ? '    selected="selected"' : '', '>', $r->post_title, '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: by children, you mean children of posts or what? also can you paste the code for other menu here

Comment: Yes @sven i have a bit of code that allows me to assign one custom post type as the parent of another (county as a parent of an area)

Comment: @sven also this is all the code i have i am using standard wp_list_pages() to create my top level navigation and jquery to show the drop down when hovering over a particular nav item

Comment: `bit of code that allows me to assign one custom post type as the parent of another`, what you actually do in that code?

Comment: @sven I have added the parent selector code to the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general logic that can be used to fetch the child custom posts

What I've assumed here is, You create a `county` post, then you create a `area` post and from parent metabox you select the desired `county` post and save the post id in `post_parent`

```
function wpse_128630_cp( $post_type = 'county', $post_parent = '', $posts_per_page = -1 ){
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'post_parent' => $post_parent ,
    'order' => 'desc'
 );
 $menu = new WP_Query( $args );
 if(!empty($menu)) { return $menu;}
 else{
    //To debug, uncomment below code
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($menu);
    //echo "</pre>";
 }
}
<ul class="wpse-parent menu">
<?php $menu = wpse_128630_cp();
while ( $menu->have_posts() ) : $menu->the_post(); ?>
<li class="menu-item">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php
        $submenu = wpse_128630_cp( 'area', get_the_ID() ); 
        if(!empty($submenu)){ ?>
            <ul class="wpse-sub-menu menu"> <?php
                while ( $submenu->have_posts() ) : $submenu->the_post(); ?>
                    <li class="menu-item">
                        <a href="<?php $submenu->the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $submenu->the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul><?php
        }?>
  </li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Do i add the function part of your answer into my functions file or does this all go in my header.php file where my menu code is?

Comment: functions file will do, I'm adding a bit explanation of what I understood from your situation and answering as per that

Comment: I may be doing it wrong but this did not work it just returns a completely blank page everywhere. I have separated the function into my functions.php file and everything else in my header.php file in the relevant place.

Comment: I may have been unclear in my question but i would like to return a list of all posts in a custom post type and all of their children. So they display something like this...

  County >
     area
     area
     area
  County >
     area
     area
     area

Comment: Childerns post type is same as parent or different ? because you said parent is of cpt `county`, while children is of cpt `area`, also you said you get a blank page, does it shows any error, can you check your error logs

Comment: Different. You are correct county is a parent of area.

Comment: so do you get any error or something, can you check logs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12313/discussion-between-sven-and-jonhodson1984)

Comment: Apologies @sven my battery died...

Comment: So you couldn't get it working?